# How to use CPU in Tensorflow 2 globally

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I know I can set

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model.predict(...)
```

to use the CPU (or GPU) with Tensorflow 2.0, however, is there a way to set this at the beginning of a script to use the CPU exclusively?

In Tensorflow 1.x it was possible to use

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 0})
```

but it was depreciated.

Is there a new way to do it?

Comment: a round about way would be to do `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'`

Comment: Thank you, however it helped to stop it from using the GPU to compute things, but still used GPU memory somehow. I ended up uninstalling CUDA etc as I won't need it for now.

Comment: you can also do `tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')`.